# Angular 4 SimpleChanges cannot catch date object changed

Tags: angular

I have two components, A is parent component, and B is child component of A.

In component A, I have a date input with a time input, and pass the selected date and time as the input for B component.

Inside component B, I have my logic to display content based on the selected date and time. And I use ngOnChanges() to detect if the selectedDateTime value has been changed.

However, if I only change the time part, seems like SimpleChanges cannot detect the changes.

I printout selectedDateTime and SimpleChanges in component B to see what the value is. SimpleChanges will not printout anything if I only change the time part in component A. But if I change date and time, it worked.

I do not know which part of my code caused the problem, and sorry I could not show the code here.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you passing data& time in two different object to B. or you are sending single Date object?

Comment: single date object

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gajyms.. seems like coming.. aren't u looking for this?

Comment: Cheers Manoj, I could get the value of SimpleChanges as well. But if I only change the time input and not change the date input, then it stops working.

Comment: Code shared by @Manoj is capturing changes to 'Date only', 'Time only' & 'both Date & time' ... so your questions should be answered